# Showing Upcoming Select Options with logic to Previous Selected Select Field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm receiving the data from api like cites nested into state objects

Example:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'State One',
    cities: [
      {
        id: 1,
        state: 'State One',
        name: 'City One'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        state: 'State One',
        name: 'City Two'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        state: 'State One',
        name: 'City Three'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'State 2',
    cities: [
      {
        id: 4,
        state: 'State 2',
        name: 'City 5'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have to give the Select options of the Cities according to Parent State. Lets say User selected `State One` in State Select Field then There should be only cities options of the `State One` in next City Field
How to Configure it ?

Currently; I have created hollow structure of the Select Input Fields but can't find anything how can I configure it. I need little help or any idea to start with.

This is current code;

```
<Col lg="6" md="12" className="mb-1">
<Label className="form-label  py-1" for="state">
    State
</Label>{' '}
<Row></Row>
<Select
    id="state"
    options={stateOptions}
    defaultValue={stateOptions[0]}
    onChange={(choice) => console.log(choice.value)}
/>
</Col>
<Col lg="6" md="12" className="mb-1">
<Label className="form-label  py-1" for="city">
    City
</Label>{' '}
<Row></Row>
<Select
    id="city"
    classNamePrefix="select"
    options={cityOptions}
    onChange={(choice) => console.log(choice.value)}
/>
</Col>
```

I have seen some articles but they suggest to use npm libraries but I can't use them because data is a lot different then that I want to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the currently selected state and update the cities that the second Select takes.

Also added some comments to explain what the functions are doing.

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);
  const [city, setCity] = useState(null);

  const onStateChange = (option) => {
    setState(option);

    // to remove city if a different state is selected
    if (!option || option?.value !== state?.value) setCity(null);
  };

  const onCityChange = (option) => {
    setCity(option);
  };

  // a separate useState for cities is not needed
  // as cities depend on the selected state, it can be determined when state changes
  const cities = useMemo(() => {
    if (!state) return [];
    return getOptions(data.find((el) => el.id === state.value).cities);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Select options={states} value={state} onChange={onStateChange} />
      <hr />
      <Select options={cities} value={city} onChange={onCityChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit codesandboxer-example (forked)]